# How to get "set-up" for using JDBC to query a database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, properties

**BACKGROUND:-**
I am following [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html) to learn JDBC, and in the first section named "[Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)", I need some help.

The last three sections of this page (named Compile and package the samples, Create databases, tables, and populate tables, and Run the samples) are running some `cmd commands` for *Creating and packaging the sample codes* (given with the tutorial) into a `jar` file, then *creating a new database* (and creating tables in it and populating them), and then *running the sample sources* (given with the tutorial).

**I do not want to create a new database and follow the tutorial exactly, so instead I have already created a test database in MySQL and created its tables and populated them. So I just want to get the concepts and write my own code and practice.**

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:-**
What I have done before this (following the guide in the tutorial) is that I have modified a couple of `XML` Properties files (which also came with the tutorial) to give the values of my `DBMS` (mysql), `my database name` (the *tutorial gives the value of the database they are going to create, and i gave the name of the database I have already created in MySQL workbench*), `DB.User`, `DB.Password`, and other properties.

*This properties file will be referred to from the code* (which creates the connection, [I have copied it here](http://pastebin.com/NZhKJWAw), the methods under consideration are `main(String [] args)`, `getConnection()`, and `setProperties(String Filename))`

**QUESTION:-**

SO my question is that instead of running the commands which are setting up the new database, compiling and packaging the sample codes (distributed with the tutorial), and then running the samples, i.e.

```
ant jar

ant create-mysql-database

ant setup
```

**what will be the commands I'll need to execute, or steps I'll need to take, to set-up/get started, such that I do not want to create a new database, andwant to learn to access and query an already created database.**

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is to download the Connector/J from mysql.com and configure your project build path to include the JAR file.

Then you can use JDBC to connect to your existing database.